# Modify URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Consider I have URL which looks like this:

```
www.xyz.com/databaseName/index.php?/Controller/method
```

which works fine.

however I want to modify URL i.e if I enter

```
www.xyz.com - I should be taken to Above URL.
```

Is there anyway to in codeigniter to do so?

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable `modrewrite` module in apache, .htaccess to rewrite index.php

now open your application/config/config.php 
in that change index_page setting as below

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

now  open your application/config/routes.php

in that change default_controller setting as below

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'controllername';
```